# PyMySQL - Using a string as cursor.execute argument

Tags: python, sql, pymysql

My problem here involves passing a string inside `cursor.execute` below

```
import pymsyql
import json

connection = pymysql.connect(
        host='localhost', user='u_u_u_u_u',
        password='passwd', db='test',
        charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
)

def get_data(table):
    try:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = """
                SELECT * FROM %s;
            """
            cursor.execute(sql, (table,))
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            return json.dumps([dict(ix) for ix in result])

    except (TypeError, pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        pass

get_data('table_1')

connection.close()
```

I get the error

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''table_1'' at line 1")
```

It seems that `execute` does not want a string passed as an argument; when I enter a string directly, like `cursor.execute(sql, ('table_1',))`, I get the same error.

I'm puzzled as to what is causing the issue, the dual-quotes `''table_1''` are confusing. Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Comment: You, unfortunately, can't specify table names this way. You have to `format()` the table name into the query and you're responsible for sanitising that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass a table name as a parameter, alas.  You have to munge it into the query string:

```
        sql = """
            SELECT * FROM `{0}`;
        """.format(table)
        cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: We both expressed the same sentiment about the fact you can't do this. Why can't it actually be implemented?

Comment: @roganjosh . . . You can only pass constants as parameters.  Not identifiers, function names, operators, and so on.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I'd already put a comment under the answer before you answered saying the same thing. It's a common question and both our replies say "unfortunately"/ "alas". My question was why this cannot be supported in the syntax since it obviously has value?

Comment: @roganjosh . . . Because one purpose of stored queries is to cache the execution plan.  You need all this information to compile the query.

Comment: I think @roganjosh is speaking from more of a sentimental position; the "why" question might be rhetorical

Comment: In part I was, but since it's so fundamental I assumed there was a practical limitation that I was not aware of, and that's answered by the response. I need to understand more about what happens in python on a fundamental level when I define a query because I don't understand why compiling a query with variable data inserts should be any more expensive/less possible than the table you're inserting into. But that's probably my limitation in understanding as of now.